# How to set multiple strings according to user's request? And then sort them and put in an array of strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I received the following question:
Write a program that receives the user's number of friends from the user.
Once the number is received, the program will record the members' names.
Keep the names in the array (it will be a string array, i.e. a char ** array) so that each cell in the array points to the beginning of a string.
Then sort the array in alphabetical order (using the strcmp function and swap between pointers) and print the member names in order.

So far this is what I did and I don't understand why it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int choice = 0;

    int i = 0;

printf("Enter number of friends: ");
scanf_s("%d", &choice);

char* friends = (char*)malloc(choice * 50 * sizeof(char));


for (i = 0; i < choice; i++)
{
    printf("Enter name of friend %d: ", (i + 1));
    scanf_s("%s", &friends[i]);
}

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You seem to have missed this part: _it will be a string array, i.e. a char ** array_ [Malloc a 2D array in C](//stackoverflow.com/q/36890624)

Comment: `friends`is an array of characters, i.e., a string. You are `scanf`ing into character position 1, then 2, etc.

Comment: I don't understand how to do that, can you please explain?

Comment: The following error seems to me:
Exception thrown at 0x7A69D3EC (ucrtbased.dll) in Q4.exe: 0xC0000005: Location of write violation access 0x00B21000

Comment: "*a string array, i.e. a `char ** array`*" wrong again. A `char**` is **not** an array of strings, but just *one single* pointer, a pointer to a pointer of `char` in fact.

Comment: Why the magic `50`. There is nothing about it in the requirements you post.

Comment: "*the program will record the members' names*" your immediate question back should have been: "What would be the maximum size for those names?"

Comment: A single "*it doesn't work*" is probably the worth trouble report one can give. Please let us know the expected behaviour compared to the observed behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never cast malloc as you did in your code.

```
char* friends = (char*)malloc(choice * 50 * sizeof(char));
```

If you declared `friends` as a pointer as above, `friends[i]` is only the `i_th` character in string `friends` (for example, with `friends = "abcd",  friends[0] = 'a', friends[1] = 'b'`and so on).

If you want to store all names, you should use 2D array, double pointer, or an array of pointer:

```
char friends[choice][50]; // (1)
```

OR

```
char * friends[choice];  // (2)
```

OR

```
char ** friends;  // (3)
```

For solution (2), you have to allocate for each pointer in array `friends` (do not forget to free the pointer at the end of program):

```
for(int i = 0; i < choice; i++) {
   friends[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
   if (!friends[i])
     // handle the error of malloc function
     return -1;
}
```

Then for scanf function (you can use `fgets` instead of `scanf`):

```
scanf("%49s", friends[i]);
```

If you want to use double pointer (solution (3)), you have to allocate for pointer `friends` then for each pointer `friend[i]` (do not forget to free all pointers at the end of program):

```
friends = malloc(sizeof(char *)*  choice);
if (!friends)
     // handle the error of malloc function
     return -1;
for(int i = 0; i < choice; i++) {
   friends[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
   if (!friends[i])
     // handle the error of malloc function
     return -1;
}
```

One attention, solutions (1) and (2) require VLAs to be available. They are with C since C99 and became optional since C11. Thanks @alk

Comment: Your solutions (1) and (2) require VLAs to be available. They are with C since C99 and became optional since C11. (C++ does not know them at all, BTW)

Comment: No need to cast `malloc()` & friends in C.

Comment: i dont cast, i just copy the code of OP for the first line. I agree with you for first and second solution

Comment: in fact if we know `choice` value before we can use `#define choice 100`, for example